# How to change row color in Kendo UI Grid based on hidden column ID?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a KendoGrid and I have a coupe hidden ID columns, I need to change the color of the row when the globalGroupLevel is a 0. I am not sure how to do this because I'm generating my grid from an external javascript file. I have looked over the kendo docs, they show something similar to what I need to do using templates, but that is when everything is done in the view and not from an external javascript file. Any ideas or direction would help out alot.

Here is the grid

```
$("#CatalogGrid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        data: catalogData
    },
    columns: [
       { field: "globalGroupID", title: "Group ID", hidden: true },
       { field: "globalGroupLevel", title: "globalGroupLevel", hidden: true },
       { field: "globalGroupName", title: "Group Name", width:350 },
       { field: "isRequired", title: "!", width:20 },
       { field: "optionName", title: "Option Name" }
    ],
    change: function (e) {

    },
    scrollable: true,
    pageable: false,
    selectable: "row",
    height: 500
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Grid dataBound event for this. See [Dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/uFugU) I made for you.

```
dataBound: function(e) {
  var data = this.dataSource.data();
  $.each(data, function (i, row) {
    if (row.get("globalGroupLevel") == 0) {
        var element = $('tr[data-uid="' + row.uid + '"] ');
        element.addClass("colored-row");
    }
  });
}
```